# pip installed but not in /usr/bin

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Today I decided to upgrade pip. The installation went fine, but the result weren't that I want to see. Now `/usr/bin` folder doesn't have pip. After that I wanted to check some command and got this

```
which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
which -a python
/home/ihor/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

How can I change folder were is pip? Because in PyCharm my Project Interpreter path is `/usr/bin/python3.6` and now I can't install modules with pip in terminal.

Please can anyone help me? This is really bugging me as I can't use many defalt ubuntu programs because of this.

OS version:Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue? You're saying if you do `pip install numpy` that you won't get `numpy` in your Pycharm envrionment? I think this has very little to do with where `pip` is located and more to do with where `pip` installs to. I am not clear on what you're asking though: try to clarify.

Comment: Is the way to install pip in /usr/bin folder as it was before?

Comment: Is that *actually* what you want? Are you sure you don't want your *packages* to be installed where your `/usr/bin/python3.6` interpreter can pick them up? Note that this is *irrelevant* to where your `pip` bin resides on your file system.

Comment: Actually it would be great. Is the way how can I install packages in `/usr/bin/python3.6`?

Comment: There is only one way you can overwrite `/usr/bin/pip`, by updating the related package with `apt`: `apt upgrade python-pip`. When you try to upgrade `pip` by issuing `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` (what you presumably did and what you shouldn't do), Ubuntu will not let you overwrite files from its own package. Instead, it will install an additional copy of `pip` to `/usr/local/bin` as a safety measure. You should reinstall `pip` with `apt` and use it.

Comment: Oh I see that you are using Python 3 - the related package is named `python3-pip`, install that instead of `python-pip`.

Comment: @hoefling thank you for reply. Last time I have installed it with command `sudo easy_install pip3`. So now firstly, I have to do uninstall it with `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3-pip` and then install pip with `apt install python3-pip`. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, then check whether `/usr/bin/pip3` becomes available again: `which -a pip3` should list `/usr/bin/pip3`. Once you have verified `pip3` working again, e.g. `/usr/bin/pip3 -V` or `/usr/bin/pip3 list`, you will have to remove the executables from `/usr/local/bin` manually as AFAIK `easy_install` doesn't provide any uninstallation command: `rm /usr/local/bin/pip{,3,3.6}`.